# Laravel subdomain 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

We are running on shared hosting and running laravel on main domain that is `example.com` , everything is working perfectly fine.

We have crated a sudbomain `test.example.com`  by vising *Subdomains manager* in *cPanel* and pointed it's document root to `/public_html/test`

As soon as we visit `test.example.com` we get **500 Internal Server Error**

Initial laravel's .htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

We have changed.

```
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

to

```
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Now if we visit `test.example.com` it redirect to `tests.example.com/test` and everything works normally.

But we not sure why it is redirecting browser to `tests.example.com/test` ?

**Updated**

After further research we found that.

If we remove this line.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then both maindomain and subdomain working perfectly fine. But is it OK to remove this line.

In short we want to run laravel on main domain and something else on subdomain.

Comment: what if you go tests.example.com/public ?

Comment: There nothing in `test.example.com`, just file `index.php` with `phpinfo();` in it.

Comment: You mean that /public_html/test dont have laravel inside ? Just index.php ?

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius If we remove, `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` then both subdomain and main domain works nornally. But not sure if is it ok to remote this.

Comment: Yes `/public_html/test` folder don't contain laravel, it  just contain `index.php` file. Laravel is installed in `/public_html` ( main domain )

Comment: You can create alias in sites-enabled/000-default (if you dont know what i mean, i can show u example) or try to create .htaccess in /test folder, have you tried already ?

Comment: Oh shared hosting, I don't have option to visit and edit `sites-enabled/000-default`. The only what I have to edit `.htaccess`. Ok but what to place in `/test/.htaccess` file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a restriction on `test` subdomain.
Also, you have to avoid removing trailing slash for folders (otherwise: loop -> 500 error).

Your htaccess would then become

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Don't touch anything when coming from test subdomain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't had the .htaccess file in the subdomain public_html folder, so if you're working with a subdomain, just copy the .htaccess file from the original domain to the subdomain folder (in the case is the exact same app).