# throws 500 error , laravel 4.2 on hosting at subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

All code is at root and a few urls are working while few of them are not.

I hope this is issue is related to .htaccess.

What the normal .htaccess code that I have is --

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

you can check here by clicking on live url -- http://nfs.wdm.net.au/ and then going to signup form

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

I have also gone with belew thread but come up with same issue.no clue at all --

[Laravel subdomain 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013448/laravel-subdomain-500-error)

Althogh same code is running fine at another server without subdomain

Comment: I'm getting javascript related errors.. so what does the laravel log say when you visit the route?

Comment: @kaspars please recheck now, I have removed js errors now, thank you for looking in to that

Comment: I don't see signup form. "Register Your School" reverts to the home page.

Comment: Thanks to all , I have resolved this, i got clue about the problem using log available in laravel function.